# How to fix com.apple.dock.extra?

Tags: macos, dock

I'm a gamer and one day  i was playing mine craft when this blabbering thing just showed up. I went to activity monitor and there was a process called `com.apple.dock.extra`. From the first day there was a annoying voice all the time and when i went to internet pages, i could not scroll down as it would go back up to the top again. Just yesterday i was playing mine craft when my up key stopped working. After some investigating, i think it has to do with com.apple.dock.extra. Whenever i press up, the annoying little black box goes up to multiple links and says them out to me. Finally, there is a big black box that appears telling me where my system is. My computer is a 13 inch MacBook Air version 10.7.4 and i have Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4. I have a 1.8 GHZ processor. Could someone PLEASE tell me how to fix it, as this is my school computer.

Comment: Does this happen when you quit Finder (open finder then press command+q)?

Answer (score -1):

You could try this fix:

In Finder use the Go to and go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/XPCServices`

In XPCServices Folder and **move** the `com.apple.dock.extra.xpc` file to desktop.

Then go back to the activity monitor and force quit the process and test!

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4263912 user jximo 07

Comment: NO! DO NOT DO THIS! Never ever delete anything inside /System.

Comment: @ganbustein you are right, lets not delete, lets just move it for now.